# How do I implement Reader using free monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad

Ok, so I have figured out how to implement `Reader` (and `ReaderT`, not shown) using the [`operational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Operational

data ReaderI r a where
    Ask :: ReaderI r r

type Reader r a = Program (ReaderI r) a

ask :: Reader r r
ask = singleton Ask

runReader :: forall r a. Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader = interpretWithMonad evalI
    where evalI :: forall b. ReaderI r b -> (r -> b)
          evalI Ask = id
```

But I can't figure out for my life how to do this with free monads (I'm using Edward Kmett's [`free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package).  The closest I've gotten is this, which I understand is cheating (something about how `((->) r)` is already a monad):

```
import Control.Monad.Free

type Reader r a = Free ((->) r) a

ask :: Reader r r
ask = Free Pure

runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader (Pure a) _ = a
runReader (Free k) r = runReader (k r) r

-- Or, more simply and tellingly:
--
-- > runReader = retract
```

Even if this wasn't as dumb as I suspect it is, it's not what I want because what I want, basically, is to be able to inspect a `Reader` as data...

Comment: I don't think it can be done without a function type somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it can be done except they way you have.  But, I don't think this is unique to reader.  Consider the free monad version of writer

```
data WriterF m a = WriterF m a deriving (Functor)

type Writer m = Free (WriterF m)
```

obviously, `WriterF` is isomorphic to writer, but this does behave the way we would expect with the simple algebra

```
algebraWriter :: Monoid m => WriterF m (m,a) -> (m,a)
algebraWriter (WriterF m1 (m2,a)) = (m1 <> m2,a)
```

thus

```
runWriter :: Monoid m => Writer m a -> (m,a)
runWriter (Pure a) = (mempty,a)
runWriter (Free x) = algebraWriter . fmap runWriter $ x
```

Similarly, I think of the Free reader as

```
type ReaderF r = (->) r

type Reader r = Free (ReaderF r)
```

I like this, because adding them gives you the state monad

```
type State x = Free ((ReaderF x) :+: (WriterF x))

runState :: State x a -> x -> (a,x)
runState (Pure a) x                    = (a,x)
runState (Free (Inl f)) x              = runState (f x) x
runState (Free (Inr (WriterF x f))) _  = runState f x
```

Note, that your operational solution could be made to work with `Free` by using the "free functor", as can anything that works with operational

```
data FreeFunctor f x = forall a. FreeFunctor (f a) (a -> x)
```

but, that `FreeFunctor ReaderI` is also isomorphic to `(->)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've been looking at this for 3 hours now, and I think I found something I like better.  Since the `Reader` applicative is the same as the `Reader` monad, we can try an applicative version of `operational`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, GADTs, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Applicative

data ProgramA instr a where
    Pure  :: a -> ProgramA r a
    Ap    :: ProgramA r (a -> b) -> ProgramA r a -> ProgramA r b
    Instr :: instr a -> ProgramA instr a

infixl `Ap`

instance Functor (ProgramA instr) where
    fmap f (Pure a) = Pure (f a)
    fmap f (ff `Ap` fa) = ((f .) <$> ff) `Ap` fa
    fmap f instr = Pure f `Ap` instr

instance Applicative (ProgramA instr) where
    pure = Pure
    (<*>) = Ap

interpretA :: Applicative f =>
              (forall a. instr a -> f a)
           -> ProgramA instr a
           -> f a
interpretA evalI (Pure a) = pure a
interpretA evalI (ff `Ap` fa) = interpretA evalI ff <*> interpretA evalI fa
interpretA evalI (Instr i) = evalI i

data ReaderI r a where
    Ask :: ReaderI r r

type Reader r a = ProgramA (ReaderI r) a

ask :: Reader r r
ask = Instr Ask

runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader = interpretA (\Ask -> id)

instance Monad (ProgramA (ReaderI r)) where
    return = pure
    ma >>= f = runReader <$> fmap f ma <*> ask
```

The structure of a `ProgramA (ReaderI r) a)` can be inspected more straightforwardly than either `Program (ReaderI r) a` or `Free ((->) r) a`.