# What can Arrows do that Monads can't?

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows

Arrows seem to be gaining popularity in the Haskell community, but it seems to me like Monads are more powerful. What is gained by using Arrows? Why can't Monads be used instead?

Comment: This is a bit too broad to be a good Stack Overflow question.  Can you make it more specific?

Comment: "Arrows seem to be gaining popularity in the Haskell community" - That's not my impression actually; arrows seem to have turned out to be a bit of a dead end AFAICT. Hopefully the pieces will come together for some  more powerful and useful abstractions built around Category and become standardized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've always found it difficult to think of the issue in these terms: what is gained by using arrows. As other commenters have mentioned, every monad can trivially be turned into an arrow. So a monad can do all the arrow-y things. However, we can make Arrows that are not monads. That is to say, we can make types that can do these arrow-y things without making them support monadic binding. It might not seem like the case, but the monadic bind function is actually a pretty restrictive (hence powerful) operation that disqualifies many types.

See, to support bind, you have to be able to assert that that regardless of the input type, what's going to come out is going to be wrapped in the monad.

```
(>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

But, how would we define bind for a type like `data Foo a = F Bool a` Surely, we could combine one Foo's a with another's but how would we combine the Bools. Imagine that the Bool marked, say, whether or not the value of the other parameter had changed. If I have `a = Foo False whatever` and I bind it into a function, I have no idea whether or not that function is going to change `whatever`. I can't write a bind that correctly sets the Bool. This is often called the problem of static meta-information. I cannot inspect the function being bound into to determine whether or not it will alter `whatever`.

There are several other cases like this: types that represent mutating functions, parsers that can exit early, etc. But the basic idea is this: monads set a high bar that not all types can clear. Arrows allow you to compose types (that may or may not be able to support this high, binding standard) in powerful ways without having to satisfy bind. Of course, you do lose some of the power of monads.

Moral of the story: there's nothing an arrow can do that monad cannot, because a monad can always be made into an arrow. However, sometimes you can't make your types into monads but you still want to allow them to have most of the compositional flexibility and power of monads.

Many of these ideas were inspired by the superb [Understanding Haskell Arrows](http://ertes.de/new/tutorials/arrows.html) ([backup](http://vrici.digitalkingdom.org/%7Erlpowell/media/public/haskell_arrow.txt))

Comment: _"There's nothing an arrow can do that monad cannot, because a monad can always be made into an arrow. However, sometimes you can't make your types into monads but you still want to allow them to have most of the compositional flexibility and power of monads."_ - aren't those two sentences mutually exclusive? The first one also directly contradicts the first paragraph of [the page you link to](http://ertes.de/new/tutorials/arrows.html) where the following is stated: "The arrow interface is more general, thus allowing some control structures, which cannot be expressed in the monadic framework."

Comment: Ahh this is an interesting semantic issue. Perhaps one of the sources of confusion around arrows and monads. Let me try to clarify. There's nothing that an arrow can do that a monad cannot do, insofar as it is an arrow. However, insofar as it is the type of something that cannot be made into a monad, it can support things that a monad cannot. This still seems confusing but I can't figure out a better way to say it. The arrow *allows* instances that monad doesn't but the "thing the monad cannot do" isn't an arrow-y thing, it's whatever disqualified the arrow instance from being a monad.

Comment: @ErikHinton: I would add this: there's a difference as well as what an action can do when executed and what a user of the action can do with it other than executing it. AFAIK, an `Arrow` parser can't parse anything that a `Monad` parser can't parse, so in that sense executing the `Arrow` can't do any more than the `Monad` could; but you can write an `Arrow` parser that can be externally analyzed to predict a lot of its runtime behavior before running it, in ways that the `Monad` interface cannot support. See my answer for an example of this, but applied to the `Reader` `Applicative`.

Comment: Possible replacements for broken "Understanding Haskell Arrows" link (unable to find page on internet archive):  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows or http://lpaste.net/94914

Comment: [Understanding Haskell Arrows](http://vrici.digitalkingdom.org/~rlpowell/media/public/haskell_arrow.txt)

Answer (score 13):

Every monad gives rise to an arrow

```
newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli (a -> m b)
instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where
   id = Kleisli return
   (Kleisli f) . (Kleisli g) = Kleisli (\x -> (g x) >>= f)
instance Monad m => Arrow (Kleisli m) where
   arr f = Kleisli (return . f)
   first (Kleisli f) = Kleisli (\(a,b) -> (f a) >>= \fa -> return (fa,b))
```

But, there are arrows which are not monads.  Thus, there are arrows which do things that you can't do with monads.  A good example is the arrow transformer to add some static information

```
data StaticT m c a b = StaticT m (c a b)
instance (Category c, Monoid m) => Category (StaticT m c) where
   id = StaticT mempty id
   (StaticT m1 f) . (StaticT m2 g) = StaticT (m1 <> m2) (f . g)
instance (Arrow c, Monoid m) => Arrow (StaticT m c) where
   arr f = StaticT mempty (arr f)
   first (StaticT m f) = StaticT m (first f)
```

this arrow tranformer is usefull because it can be used to keep track of static properties of a program.  For example, you can use this to instrument your API to statically measure how many calls you are making.

Comment: Conversely, `ArrowApply` [gives you a monad](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowMonad).

Comment: Could you elaborate on your `StaticT` example? I don't understand why that couldn't be done with a `State` or `Writer` monad.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm going to cheat slightly here by changing the question from `Arrow` to `Applicative`.  A lot of the same motives apply, and I know applicatives better than arrows.  (And in fact, [every `Arrow` is also an `Applicative`](http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/arrow-category-applicative-part-i/) but [not vice-versa](http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/arrow-category-applicative-part-iia/), so I'm just taking it down a bit further down the slope to `Functor`.)

Just like every `Monad` is an `Arrow`, every `Monad` is also an `Applicative`.  There are `Applicatives` that are not `Monad`s (e.g., `ZipList`), so that's one possible answer.

But assume we're dealing with a type that admits of a `Monad` instance as well as an `Applicative`.  Why might we sometime use the `Applicative` instance instead of `Monad`?  Because `Applicative` is less powerful, and that comes with benefits:

1. There are things that we know that the `Monad` can do which the `Applicative` cannot.  For example, if we use the `Applicative` instance of `IO` to assemble a compound action from simpler ones, none of the actions we compose may use the results of any of the others.  All that applicative `IO` can do is execute the component actions and combine their results with pure functions.
2. `Applicative` types can be written so that we can do powerful static analysis of the actions before executing them.  So you can write a program that inspects an `Applicative` action before executing it, figures out what it's going to do, and uses that to improve performance, tell the user what's going to be done, etc.

As an example of the first, I've been working on designing a kind of [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) calculation language using `Applicative`s.  The type admits of a `Monad` instance, but I've deliberately avoided having that, because I want the queries to be *less* powerful than what `Monad` would allow.  `Applicative` means that each calculation will bottom out to a predictable number of queries.

As an example of the latter, I'll use a toy example from [my still-under-development operational `Applicative` library](https://github.com/sacundim/free-operational). If you write the `Reader` monad as an operational `Applicative` program instead, you can examine the resulting `Reader`s to count how many times they use the `ask` operation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Applicative.Operational

-- | A 'Reader' is an 'Applicative' program that uses the 'ReaderI' 
-- instruction set.
type Reader r a = ProgramAp (ReaderI r) a

-- | The only 'Reader' instruction is 'Ask', which requires both the
-- environment and result type to be @r@.
data ReaderI r a where
    Ask :: ReaderI r r

ask :: Reader r r
ask = singleton Ask

-- | We run a 'Reader' by translating each instruction in the instruction set
-- into an @r -> a@ function.  In the case of 'Ask' the translation is 'id'.
runReader :: forall r a. Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader = interpretAp evalI
    where evalI :: forall x. ReaderI r x -> r -> x
          evalI Ask = id

-- | Count how many times a 'Reader' uses the 'Ask' instruction.  The 'viewAp'
-- function translates a 'ProgramAp' into a syntax tree that we can inspect.
countAsk :: forall r a. Reader r a -> Int
countAsk = count . viewAp
    where count :: forall x. ProgramViewAp (ReaderI r) x -> Int
          -- Pure :: a -> ProgamViewAp instruction a
          count (Pure _) = 0
          -- (:<**>) :: instruction a 
          --         -> ProgramViewAp instruction (a -> b)
          --         -> ProgramViewAp instruction b
          count (Ask :<**> k) = succ (count k)
```

As best as I understand, you can't write `countAsk` if you implement `Reader` as a monad.  (My understanding comes [from asking right here in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426320/how-do-i-implement-reader-using-free-monads), I'll add.)

This same motive is actually one of the ideas behind `Arrow`s.  One of the big motivating examples for `Arrow` was a parser combinator design that uses "static information" to get better performance than monadic parsers.  What they mean by "static information" is more or less the same as in my `Reader` example: it's possible to write an `Arrow` instance where the parsers can be inspected very much like my `Reader`s can.  Then the parsing library can, before executing a parser, inspect it to see if it can predict ahead of time that it will fail, and skip it in that case.

In one of the direct comments to your question, jberryman mentions that arrows may in fact be losing popularity.  I'd add that as I see it, `Applicative` is what arrows are losing popularity to.

---

References:

- Paolo Capriotti & Ambrus Kaposi, ["Free Applicative Functors"](http://paolocapriotti.com/blog/2013/04/03/free-applicative-functors/).  Very highly recommended.
- Gergo Erdi, ["Static analysis with Applicatives"](http://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2012-12-01-static_analysis_with_applicatives/).  Inspirational, but I it hard to follow...

Comment: I'm not sure if the claim that Applicatives do not create arrows is true.  Applicatives lead to arrow transformers `newtype AppArrow f c a b = AppArrow (f (c a b))`.  And, it should be possible to inject values from the applicative functor to the resulting arrow.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't quite right.  It's like asking why would you eat oranges instead of apples, since apples seem more nutritious all around.

Arrows, like monads, are a way of expressing computations, but they have to obey a different set of [laws](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t%3aArrow).  In particular, the laws tend to make arrows nicer to use when you have function-like things.

The Haskell Wiki lists a [few introductions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow#External_links) to arrows.  In particular, the [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows) is a nice high level introduction, and the [tutorial](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf) by John Hughes is a good overview of the various kinds of arrows.

For a real world example, compare [this tutorial](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/03-arrows.html) which uses Hakyll 3's arrow-based interface, with roughly [the same thing](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/03-rules-routes-compilers.html) in Hakyll 4's monad-based interface.

Answer (score 1):

I always found one of the really practical use cases of arrows to be **stream programming**.

Look at this:

```
data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a)
data SF a b = SF (a -> (b, SF a b))
```

`SF a b` is a synchronous stream function.
You can define a function from it that transforms `Stream a` into `Stream b` that never hangs and always outputs one `b` for one `a`:

```
(<<$>>) :: SF a b -> Stream a -> Stream b
SF f <<$>> Stream a as = let (b, sf') = f a
                         in  Stream b $ sf' <<$>> as
```

There is an `Arrow` instance for `SF`. In particular, you can *compose* `SF`s:

```
(>>>) :: SF a b -> SF b c -> SF a c
```

Now try to do this in monads. It doesn't work well. You might say that `Stream a == Reader Nat a` and thus it's a monad, but the monad instance is very inefficient. Imagine the type of `join`:

```
join :: Stream (Stream a) -> Stream a
```

You have to extract the diagonal from a stream of streams. This means `O(n)` complexity for the `n`th element, but using the `Arrow` instance for `SF`s gives you `O(1)` in principle! (And also deals with time and space leaks.)